# Pandas Dataframe Entire Column to String Data Type

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I know you can do this with a series, but I can't seem to do this with a dataframe.

I have the following:

```
     name     note                     age
0    jon      likes beer on tuesdays      10
1    jon      likes beer on tuesdays
2    steve    tonight we dine in heck     20
3    steve    tonight we dine in heck
```

I am trying to produce the following:

```
     name     note                     age
0    jon      likes beer on tuesdays      10
1    jon      likes beer on tuesdays      10
2    steve    tonight we dine in heck     20
3    steve    tonight we dine in heck     20
```

I know how to do this with string values using group by and join, but this only works on string values. I'm having issues converting the entire column of age to a string data type in the dataframe.

Any suggestions?

Comment: if you wanna convert a column to string data type you can use ```df['age'] = df['age'].astype(str)```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`GroupBy.first`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.first.html) with [`GroupBy.transform`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.transform.html) if want repeat first values per groups:

```
g = df.groupby('name')
df['note'] = g['note'].transform(' '.join)
df['age'] = g['age'].transform('first')
```

If need processing multiple columns - it means all numeric with `first` and all strings by join you can generate dictionary by columns names with functions, pass to [`GroupBy.agg`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.agg.html) and last use [`DataFrame.join`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.join.html):

```
cols1 = df.select_dtypes(np.number).columns
cols2 = df.columns.difference(cols1).difference(['name'])
d1 = dict.fromkeys(cols2, lambda x: ' '.join(x))
d2 = dict.fromkeys(cols1, 'first')
d = {**d1, **d2}
df1 = df[['name']].join(df.groupby('name').agg(d), on='name')
```

Comment: What is "First" ?

Comment: @LunchBox - it menas first value of group.

Comment: I need to increase my knowledge of transform and group by, but this solved my problem. Thank you.

Comment: @LunchBox - It working similar like `agg`, only it repeat values to new column.